# Propagating all events from a X window

Tags: linux, accessibility, xlib, xorg

I'a currently working on a small utility, it's my first ever X project. The utility is used to draw a small circle around your mouse pointer. I use an app called Pinpoint to do the same on my Mac, it helps me find my mouse as I'm visually impaired.

The utility creates an transparent X window and draw a circle inside, it then moves that window with the mouse pointer so that the circle follows the mouse.

It currently works, except for one detail. Mouse events are not propagated up to the underlying windows. Basically, the utility makes the mouse useless.

As far as I can tell from the Xlib docs, if not otherwise specified, new windows should propagate all events. How can I fix this?

The code can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/blubber/circle-cursor it's a bit messy currently, becaue it is just a proof of concept.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply replace the cursor (mouse pointer) theme with one that has a circle drawn around it or at least is larger? That would make X do all the hard work. (I'm still going to look up how to get your program to work as I remember seeing a program that was able to draw on the screen and not absorb events.)

Comment: I tried a different mouse cursor theme but I can't find one that does the job. Even increasing the cursor size doesn't help. The problem is that the cursor changes all the time, which makes it hard for me to find. The circles are constant and easy to recognize. I though about adding a circle to one if the cursor themes that I use, but I don't really know how. Ofcourse I can figure that out, and write a small script that modifies all the cursor files.

Comment: @DanD. I am happy to gratulate your perfect grammar, especially compared to [2011](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10214/how-to-set-per-process-swapiness-for-linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing via cursor image as well, there are many ways when you won't be able to receive mouse events and only possible source would be polling with `XQueryPointer`.

With [xfixes](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/fixesproto/fixesproto.txt) extension you can subscribe to all `cursor image changed` events and get most recent shape of the cursor, and whit XRender you can set your own ( possibly animated cursor )

Comment: I've taken a look at XRender and xfixes, as far as I can tell you're suggesting listening for cursor image change events, and then using XRender's CreateCursor call to create a new cursor with the old shape and my customizations?

Comment: correct, instead of moving transparent window located near cursor ( this has a lot of own potential problems: window position lagging behind cursor, interactions with wm and composite manager etc ) you update current cursor shape image, and do this each time other windows/clients change cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I googled around a bit and eventually found this: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/src/cursor.c which is exactly what you are talking about, only they copy the cursor to a different display, instead of altering it. I've adapted it to my needs, and it works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: nice, yes, cursor.c is doing this exactly in a way I was suggesting ( without image modification, it just mirrors external connection )